# An attempt to override an existing mapping was detected for type System.Web.IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, unity-container

I have the following error on an asp.net mvc application when I copy it to the IIS folder of our test server.

Locally it works perfectly fine:

An attempt to override an existing mapping was detected for type System.Web.IHttpHandler with name "", currently mapped to type Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, to type Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.

the UnityConfig.cs code is like this:

```
namespace xxx.Relacionamiento.Web.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
    /// </summary>
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configured Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
        /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
        /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
        /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor(
                //new ResolvedParameter<ApplicationUserManager>("userManager"),
                //new ResolvedParameter<ApplicationSignInManager>("signInManager"),
                new ResolvedParameter<DatosExternosService>("DatosExternos"),
                new ResolvedParameter<UserRolesServices>("UserRolesServices"),
                new ResolvedParameter<AspNetUserService>("AspNetUserService"),
                new ResolvedParameter<AsesoresService>("AsesoreService"),
                new ResolvedParameter<AsociadosService>("AsociadoService")
                ));
            container.RegisterTypes(
                AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default
               );
        }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<system.web>
    <!--<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="ES" />-->
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
    <!--<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />-->
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportVidewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
   </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
```

I already googled the error and no re[image]sults were given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `RegisterTypes` method throws `DuplicateTypeMappingException`, it is possible that you've already have a registration mapping that also matched one of defined conventions on `RegisterTypes` - which known as 'registration by convention'.

The `RegisterTypes` method returns `IUnityContainer` which has relation to `RegistrationConvention` like below:

```
public static IUnityContainer RegisterTypes(
    this IUnityContainer container,
    RegistrationConvention convention,
    bool overwriteExistingMappings = false)
```

Then, this explains how optional `overwriteExistingMappings` parameter works:

> Use this parameter to control the behavior of the `RegisterTypes` method
>   if the parameters to this method cause an existing mapping in the
>   container to be overwritten. The existing mapping may have been
>   created by a previous call to to register a type or types or during
>   the current call to the RegisterTypes method. If this parameter is set
>   to false, the method throws an `DuplicateTypeMappingException` exception
>   if it detects an attempt to overwrite an existing mapping. If the
>   parameter is set to true, the method overwrites the existing mapping
>   with a new mapping based on the other parameters to the method. The
>   default value for this parameter is **false**.

Since there are predefined `httpHandlers` set in web.config & `overwriteExistingMappings` set to **false** by default, it detects attempt to overwrite existing `httpHandlers` mapping and throwing `DuplicateTypeMappingException` as expected.

From those explanations above, you may give try to add `overwriteExistingMappings` parameter set to **true** from this code part:

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);
```

to this one:

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default, overwriteExistingMappings: true);
```

NB: This only prevents `RegisterTypes` to throw exception when doing attempt to overwrite existing mappings. If you're not sure `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler` configuration was not overwritten, register `ReportViewer` mapping in `RegisterTypes` method using DI way.

Reference:

[Registration by Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507479(v=pandp.30).aspx) (MSDN)

Additional references:

[Unity Container: Dependency Injection with Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx) (MSDN)

[Convention based registrations with Unity](http://wp.sjkp.dk/convention-based-registrations-with-unity/)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to clear any inherited HttpHandlers

```
<httpHandlers>
  <clear/>
  <add path="...
```